# C program stops in the middle of running

Tags: c

Hi im new here also im new to programming and id like you to help me on this : to problem is that after compiling and running the program it stops in the middle of it when running and i didnt know what is causing this and sorry for the unreadable previous post :
here is my program :

```
char answer[15];
char place[15];
char fullname[15];
int age;
printf("What Is Your Full Name?: ");
scanf("%s",fullname);
printf("What Is Your Age?: ");
scanf("%d",age);
printf("Where Do You Live?: ");
scanf("%s",place);

if(strcmp(place,"gafsa")==0) {
    printf("Aint a bad place you know");
}
else{
    printf("hmmm %s cool\n",place);
}

printf("your name is %s, %d year old from %s is that right?: ",fullname,age,place);
scanf("%s",answer);

if(strcmp(answer,"yes")==0){
    printf("you my friend are awesome\n");
}
else{ 
    printf("you suck\n");
}
```

and this is an image to show the problem clearly:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFTwK.png

Comment: did you try debugging?

Comment: Please turn on your compiler's warnings and read them.

Comment: im new so can you sir explain to me how and what is debugging in c programming

Comment: In c you can do some mistakes that will compile, link, then crash on run time. In order to detect this mistakes, turn the warnings of the compiler on.

Comment: @darksphere - Depends on the platform. dbx, VS

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging wikipedia **is** your friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the address of the variable:

```
scanf("%d",&age);
           ^
```

Comment: Thank you : i realy forgot to add & in scanf, silly mistake in the bigging of a long journey in programming, hope this will be the last time

Answer (score 1):

You're taking input at a memory location of value of uninitialized `age`. i.e. some garbage

Use:

`scanf("%d",&age); // notice & , pass address of variable age`